# How can I identify and extract duplicates from data frame?

Tags: r

My objective is to check if a patient is using two drugs at the same date.
In the example, patient 1 is using drug A and drug B at the same date, but I want to extract it with code.

```r
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),    
                 date = c("2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-03-02","2019-10-02","2019-10-18","2019-10-26"),    
                 drug_type = c("A","B","A","A","A","B"))      
df$date <- as.factor(df$date)
df$drug_type <- as.factor(df$drug_type)
```

In order to do this, I firstly made date and drug type factor variables.
Next I used following code:

```r
df %>%  
  mutate(lev_actdate = as.factor(actdate))%>%        
  filter(nlevels(drug_type)>1 & nlevels(date) < nrow(date))
```

But I failed. I assumed that if a patient is using two drugs at the same date, the number of levels in the date column will be less than its row number. However, now I don't know how to make it with code.

Additionally, I feel weird about following:

if I use `nlevels(df$date)`, right result will be returned, but when I use `df %>% nlevels(date)`, the error will be return with showing

> "Error in nlevels(., df$date) : unused argument (df$date)"

Could you please tell me why this occurred and how can I fix it?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like

```r
library(dplyr) 

df %>%
  group_by(id, date) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(drug_type) >= 2)
```

`df %>% nlevels(date)` is the same as `nlevels(df, date)` which is not the same as `nlevels(df$date)`. Instead of the latter youcould try `df %>% nlevels(.$date)` or perhaps `df %>% {nlevels(.$date)}`.

Comment: Thank you so much for showing so concise and efficient codes! It worked!
I would also feel grateful if you can explain about why nlevels() failed when you are available.

Comment: Added a small explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need something like this?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  summarise(drug_type_sum = toString(drug_type))
```

```
  date       drug_type_sum
  <fct>      <chr>        
1 2019-10-02 A            
2 2019-10-18 A            
3 2019-10-26 B            
4 2020-02-01 A, B         
5 2020-03-02 A
```

Comment: Thank you so much for showing so concise and efficient codes! It worked!